# react-select add border red

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm working with `react-select`, I'm trying to add border red:

this's my component select:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactSelect, { GroupBase, Props } from "react-select";

export default function InputSelect<
    Option = {
        label: string;
        value: string;
    },
    IsMulti extends boolean = false,
    Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>
>(props: Props<Option, IsMulti, Group>) {
    return (
        <ReactSelect
            {...props}
            theme={(theme) => ({ ...theme, borderRadius: 0 })}
        />
    );
}
```

and this one is my component form only the part where I use the component `InputSelect`

```
<InputSelect
    isClearable={true}
    onChange={(e) => {
        //@ts-ignore
        handlerChange("idlist", e?.value);
    }}
    options={list}  
    className={` ${active? 'border-red-500' : 'border-grey-500' } `}                        
/>
```

I just want active border red when variable `active` is `true`, currently it's not working, what's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the solution, I updated component react like:

```
<ReactSelect
    {...props}
    styles={{
        control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
          ...baseStyles,
          borderColor: props.className,
        }),
      }}
/>
```

and in my father component

```
<InputSelect
    className={`${activeBorderTipoTicket? "red" : "grey"}`}
    isClearable={true}
    onChange={(e) => {
        //@ts-ignore
        handlerChange("idlist", e?.value);
    }}
    options={list}                                                        
/>
```